# ¿como instalo una dependencia de manera manual en npm para laravel?

Tags: laravel, nodejs, vue.js, npm

buenas noches amigos desarrolladores xD, tengo un problema al usar vue-toast-notification con laravel, pues me pide que instale una dependencia de manera manual pero la verdad soy nuevo en esto y no tengo muchas ideas de donde al menos conseguir ese paquete si pudieran ayudarme lo agradeceria mucho[image: Este es el error que me lanza al intentar actualizar la carpeta de node_modules]

Acabo de Darme cuenta de que el problema que hay con el requerimiento de vue es un problema de versiones especificamente de que ptro paquete no lo tengo claro, sin embargo, instale la version 3.0 de vue, y luego me pidio la version 2.16 del mismo, esto solo lo exige para utilizar vue-toast-notification

Comment: ¿Qué versión de vue tienes en ese proyecto?

Comment: tengo la versión vue": "^2.6.12

Comment: cuando dice "you must install peer dependencies yourself", no esta diciendo que la instales manual, si no que hay una referencia que debes instalarla ejecutando los comandos de instalacion de paquetes, pero que npm no puede hacerlo automaticamente. Igual, salvo contados casos, la mayoria de esas dependencias que tenes que instalar por vos mismo, no son necesarias...

Comment: igual ahi lo que hiciste fue desinstalar una libreria...

Comment: Si el caso es que, ya intente instalando ese paquete con su debido comando " npm install vue@3.0 --save" y la verdad, la ejecucion del sitio me arroja un error, e incluso cuando, vuelvo a ejecutar "npm install" me dice que el paquete "npm WARN vue-toast-notification@2.0.1 requires a peer of vue@^3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself." y el error que me arroja en la ejecucion del sitio, es justo con el paquete vue-toast-notification

Comment: app.js:56959 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , t.createVNode) is not a function
    at app.js:56959
    at app.js:56959
    at app.js:56959
    at app.js:56959
    at Object../node_modules/vue-toast-notification/dist/index.min.js (app.js:56959)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:69038)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:2501)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:69038)
    at app.js:69203
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (app.js:69075)

Answer (score 0):

Faltó explicar el origen del entuerto. Supongo que querías mostrar una notificación emergente, encontraste alguna recomendación de `vue-toast-notification` e intentaste instalarlo con

```
 npm install vue-toast-notification
```

npm buscó en el registro la última versión estable de `vue-toast-notification`, que es la [2.0.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toast-notification), y al instalarla saltó un warning, porque   [tal como dice al inicio del README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toast-notification), las versiones 2.x requieren Vue 3.0

[image: Esto sale en NPM sobre ese paquete]

Tú intentaste resolverlo instalando vue 3, pero tu proyecto está en vue 2.6, y eso es un hecho de la causa. Instalar vue 3 encima sólo puede generar una mezcla inviable.

En esa misma tablita que mostré arriba, se indica que para Vue 2.0 corresponde usar una versión de `vue-toast-notification` de la familia 1.x. Ahora, esto es un problema, porque no existe tal cosa como una versión mayor 1.x. Si uno mira los tags del repositorio, antes de la serie 2.x [existió como máximo un tag `0.6.2`](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-toast-notification/tags)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al menos, en su `package.json` dice explícitamente [que su peer dependency es Vue 2.x](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-toast-notification/blob/0.6.2/package.json#L69-L72).

---

Raya para la suma: intenta con

```
npm install vue-toast-notification@~0.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

El inconveniente seguramente es con la compatibilidad de la versión de vue, recuerda que ahora existen "dos versiones" vue 2 y vue 3, vue 3 hace las cosas bastante distintas a vue 2; si bien vue3 es compatible con el optionAPI de vue2; es posible que la librería que instalas sea compatible con vue3 y muchas librerías se han actualizado, y seguramente ya usan compositionAPI de vue3, cosa que no será compatible si tienes una versión de vue 2.x.x por lo que cada vez que agregues paquetes de terceros, asegúrate que sea una versión compatible con tu versión de vue.